# Synchronising the data of new master with existing master-slave setup in Redis Sentinel

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

I'm a Redis beginner and I'm exploring various Sentinel configurations in my local environment. Currently, I have an established master-slave setup comprising master (A) and slave (A). I'm trying to introduce a new master, namely master (B), into the existing setup with master (A).

Here's the issue: the data written in master (A) before adding master (B) is accessible in master (B), but any writes made in master (A) after adding master (B) are not reflected in master (B). Similarly, the data in master (B) is not accessible in master (A) or slave (A).

I saw that Redis Sentinel allows multiple masters in a structure, please correct me if I'm wrong about this. Is it possible to synchronize data between these masters while ensuring data consistency? If so, I'd appreciate guidance on the steps to achieve this. Thank you!